# Why given below expression evaluates to 30 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why does this expression in javaScript evaluate to 30?

```
"37" - 7 // evaluates to 30 in javascript
```

Comment: With `+` it will concatenate... What do you expect with `"-"` ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? What would you expect a `-` operator to do?

Answer (score 3):

In this case JavaScript implicity converts "37" to 37 (number) and evaluates the expression. Bcz '-' operator makes no sense when use with strings.

If JavaScript wants a number, it will try to convert the value you give it to a number (or to NaN if it cannot perform a meaningful conversion).

For example:

```
15 + "objects"   // =>  "15 objects"
"5" * "6" // => 30 (both strings converts to number)
1 - "x" // => NaN (string can't be converted to a number)
"50" - 20 // => 30 (one string converted to number)
```

Comment: That's right. Other languages would throw an error, but JS just tinkers and transforms a string into a number. Some think it's an heresy, others that it's a very powerful feature. JS's flexibility isn't to everybody's liking.

Comment: @JeremyThille yes, I personally like this feature of implicit conversion, but one should be careful about this otherwise it can lead towards unexpected results :)

Answer (score 0):

The [subtraction operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2) converts the values on either side of itself to Numbers and then subtracts the RHS from the LRH.

> 1. Let lref be the result of evaluating AdditiveExpression.
> 2. Let lval be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let rref be the result of evaluating MultiplicativeExpression.
> 4. Let rval be GetValue(rref).
> 5. Let lnum be ToNumber(lval).
> 6. Let rnum be ToNumber(rval).
> 7. Return the result of applying the subtraction operation to lnum and rnum.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript can evaluate expressions, based on commands. In your case, you use 37 (a string) and try to (I assume remove the 7 ???), so you'd get 30 as a result.

Since JavaScript has no idea, what exactly to do with that minus, it simply converts "37" to a number and subtracts it by 7, so your result is 30. If you would use "37" + 7 instead, the 7 would get converted to a string and JavaScript would concatenate those two strings into 377.

Comment: `"37" - "7"` returns 30, not "3". Just try it in your console.